# Action Script 3 Line breaks within quotation marks

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm fairly new to the ActionScript language and I was wondering how I can add line breaks in a dynamic text field.

I have text set to appear in the text box through an array, but some of the questions are much longer than some of the others. This means that some or most of the text has gone off the screen.

I'm looking for something or the same thing/effect as the html `<br>` tag.

Any answers are appreciated and thank you for your time.
(Here is the code for the frame)

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

var nQNumber:Number = 0;
var aQuestions:Array = new Array();
var aCorrectAnswers:Array = new Array("c", "ab", "c", "c", "d", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a", "abceg", "a", "b", "a", "a")
var aUserAnswers:Array = new Array();
var cQAnswers:Array = new Array();

aQuestions[0] = "What does the evacuation siren sound like?";
aQuestions[1] = "What must you do if you hear the eacuation siren? (Multiple Answers)";
aQuestions[2] = "What must you do with cigarette lighters or matches while on the manifacturing site?";
aQuestions[3] = "Is it OK to carry a mobile phone on the manufacturing area of the site?";
aQuestions[4] = "What must you do if a chemical comes into contact with your eyes or skin?";
aQuestions[5] = "What is the maximum speed permitted on site?";
aQuestions[6] = "Who has the right of way at pedestrian crossings?";
aQuestions[7] = "Who must you report any injuries, incidents, near misses or hazards to?";
aQuestions[8] = "Where is the evacuation assembly area?";
aQuestions[9] = "Where can you access a Saftey Data Sheet? (Multiple Answers)";
aQuestions[10] = "What Personal Protective Equipment is required to be worn at all times on the manufacturing site? (Multiple Answers)";
aQuestions[11] = "Who is permitted to drive a forklift on site?";
aQuestions[12] = "When are you permitted to remove a tag?";
aQuestions[13] = "What is required before any maintenance or repairs are carried out on the plant? (Multiple answers)";
aQuestions[14] = "When should you wash your hands?";

cQAnswers[0] = "";
cQAnswers[1] = "";
cQAnswers[2] = "";
cQAnswers[3] = "";
cQAnswers[4] = "";
cQAnswers[5] = "";
cQAnswers[6] = "";
cQAnswers[7] = "";
cQAnswers[8] = "";
cQAnswers[9] = "";
cQAnswers[10] = "";
cQAnswers[11] = "";
cQAnswers[12] = "";
cQAnswers[13] = "";
cQAnswers[14] = "";

questions_txt.text = aQuestions [nQNumber];

submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quiz);

function quiz(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
     aUserAnswers.push(answers_txt.text);
     answers_txt.text = "";
     nQNumber++;
     if(nQNumber < aQuestions.length) 
     {
          questions_txt.text = aQuestions[nQNumber];
     }
     else
     {
          nextFrame();
     }
}
```

[The questions in the quotation marks in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4178t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the escape sequence `\n` to insert a new line into your text:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.text = "Line\nBreak";
addChild(textField);
```

[image]

Check out the Escape sequence chart [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef8.html)